# How to await a list of tasks asynchronously using LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I have a list of tasks that I created like this:

```
public async Task<IList<Foo>> GetFoosAndDoSomethingAsync()
{
    var foos = await GetFoosAsync();

    var tasks = foos.Select(async foo => await DoSomethingAsync(foo)).ToList();

    ...
}
```

By using `.ToList()`, the tasks should all start. Now I want to await their completion and return the results.

This works in the above `...` block:

```
var list = new List<Foo>();
foreach (var task in tasks)
    list.Add(await task);
return list;
```

It does what I want, but this seems rather clumsy. I'd much rather write something simpler like this:

```
return tasks.Select(async task => await task).ToList();
```

... but this doesn't compile. What am I missing? Or is it just not possible to express things this way?

Comment: Do you need to process `DoSomethingAsync(foo)` serially for each foo, or is this a candidate for [Parallel.ForEach<Foo>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/dd992001(v=VS.110,d=hv.2).aspx) ?

Comment: @mdisibio - `Parallel.ForEach` is blocking.  The pattern here comes from Jon Skeet's [Asynchronous C# video on Pluralsight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/Description/skeet-async).  It executes in parallel without blocking.

Comment: @mdisibio - Nope.  They run in parallel.  [Try it](https://gist.github.com/mj1856/9084379).  (Additionally, it looks like I don't need `.ToList()` if I'm just going to use `WhenAll`.)

Comment: Point taken. Depending on the how `DoSomethingAsync` is written,  the list might or might not be executed in parallel. I was able to write a test method that was and a version that was not, but in either case the behavior is dictated by the method itself, not the delegate creating the task. Sorry for the mix-up. However, if `DoSomethingAsyc` returns `Task<Foo>`, then the `await` in the delegate is not absolutely necessary...I think that was the main point I was going to try to make.

Comment: What does `GetFoosAsync()` return? @MattJohnson-Pint

Answer (score 154, accepted):

LINQ doesn't work perfectly with `async` code, but you can do this:

```
var tasks = foos.Select(DoSomethingAsync).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

If your tasks all return the same type of value, then you can even do this:

```
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

which is quite nice. `WhenAll` returns an array, so I believe your method can return the results directly:

```
return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Comment: Just wanted to point out that this can also work with `var tasks = foos.Select(foo => DoSomethingAsync(foo)).ToList();`

Comment: or even `var tasks = foos.Select(DoSomethingAsync).ToList();`

Comment: what is the reason behind it that Linq does'nt work perfectly with async code?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Because LINQ to Objects synchrously works on in-memory objects. Some limited things work, like `Select`. But most don't, like `Where`.

Comment: If we have in memory long running operation,  is it good approach to use async await there?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: The use case for `async` is freeing up threads. So, if you want to free up the UI or ASP.NET request thread, then yes.

Comment: and if that processing we are already doing in a background thread, then it's no use to put async await?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: If the operation is I/O-based, then you can use `async` to reduce threads; if it's CPU-bound and already on a background thread, then `async` wouldn't provide any benefit.

Comment: So, what if I need each task to be await in sequence, as in the case with LINQ to EF?

Comment: You just do one `await` at a time. EF does support `await`, but it doesn't support multiple simultaneous requests on the same context, so you can't do something like my answer here with `Select` followed by `WhenAll`. (Unless you use multiple db contexts).

Answer (score 8):

To expand on Stephen's answer, I've created the following extension method to keep the [fluent style](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-fluent-API-in-this-context#) of LINQ. You can then do

```
await someTasks.WhenAll()

namespace System.Linq
{
    public static class IEnumerableExtensions
    {
        public static Task<T[]> WhenAll<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> source)
        {
            return Task.WhenAll(source);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would name your extension method `ToArrayAsync`

Answer (score 4):

One issue with `Task.WhenAll` is that it would create a parallelism. In most of the cases it might be even better, but sometimes you want to avoid it. For example, reading data in batches from DB and sending data to some remote web service. You don't want to load all the batches to the memory but hit the DB once the previous batch has been processed. So, you have to break the asynchronicity. Here is an example:

```
var events = Enumerable.Range(0, totalCount/ batchSize)
   .Select(x => x*batchSize)
   .Select(x => dbRepository.GetEventsBatch(x, batchSize).GetAwaiter().GetResult())
   .SelectMany(x => x);
foreach (var carEvent in events)
{
}
```

Note `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` converting it to synchronous. DB would be hit lazily only once `batchSize` of events have been processed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Task.WaitAll` or `Task.WhenAll` whichever is approriate.

Comment: That doesn't work either.  `Task.WaitAll` is blocking, not awaitable, and won't work with a `Task<T>`.

Comment: @MattJohnson `WhenAll` ?

Comment: Yep.  That's it!  I feel dumb.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Task.WhenAll should do the trick here.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Stephen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868161/411428) it can also be expressed without `.ToList()` as follows:

```cs
var tasks = foos.Select(aFoo => aFoo.DoSomething());
await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(true);
```

Background: In some scenarios calling `.ToList()` can result in side effects executed at that time because the enumerable is then enumerated. If the enumerable is a call to a set of APIs or a set of queries, this may not be the desired behavior at that time. Without `.ToList()` the enumerable will be enumerated when the task is await.

More specifically: With (Fluent) NHibernate you'd typically avoid using `.ToList()` on queries as otherwise you may end up reading the entire result set. This may be way more data that you want.

Comment: In this case the `ToList` doesn't make much of a difference. The `Task.WhenAll` materializes immediately the supplied `IEnumerable<Task<TResult>>` to an array anyway ([source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/threading/tasks/Task.cs.html#b6d43f186de3a867)).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Fair enough. However, the implementation may change. - Generally, I avoid using `.ToList()` as it also depends on the LINQ provider in question. While at the moment, this is the one at the link you provided, the same is not necessarily true in all scenarios where you might use `.ToList()`. Definitely worth being aware of the particular implementation of the LINQ provider. Therefore, thank you for your very valuable coment, Theodor!