# What actually happens when using async/await inside a LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, c#-5.0

The following snippet compiles, but I'd expect it to await the task result instead of giving me a `List<Task<T>>`.

```
var foo = bars.Select(async bar => await Baz(bar)).ToList()
```

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868161/247702), you need to use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
var tasks = foos.Select(async foo => await DoSomethingAsync(foo)).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

But [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868087/how-to-await-a-list-of-tasks-asynchronously-using-linq#comment33110750_21868161) points out that the `async` and `await` inside the `Select()` is not needed:

```
var tasks = foos.Select(foo => DoSomethingAsync(foo)).ToList();
```

A similar question [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/32160/filtering-a-collection-by-an-async-result) where someone tries to use an async method inside a `Where()`.

So `async` and `await` inside a LINQ statement is legal syntax, but does it do nothing at all or does it have a certain use?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I recommend that you not think of this as "using `async` within LINQ". Keep in mind what's in-between the two: delegates. Several LINQ operators take delegates, and `async` can be used to create an asynchronous delegate.

So, when you have an asynchronous method `BazAsync` that returns a `Task`:

```
Task BazAsync(TBar bar);
```

then this code results in a sequence of tasks:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = bars.Select(bar => BazAsync(bar));
```

Similarly, if you use `async` and `await` within the delegate, you're creating an asynchronous delegate that returns a `Task`:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = bars.Select(async bar => await BazAsync(bar));
```

These two LINQ expressions are functionally equivalent. There are no important differences.

Just like regular LINQ expressions, the `IEnumerable<Task>` is lazy-evaluated. Only, with asynchronous methods like `BazAsync`, you usually do *not* want accidental double-evaluation or anything like that. So, when you project to a sequence of tasks, it's usually a good idea to immediately reify the sequence. This calls `BazAsync` for all the elements in the source sequence, starting all the tasks going:

```
Task[] tasks = bars.Select(bar => BazAsync(bar)).ToArray();
```

Of course, all we've done with `Select` is *start* an asynchronous operation for each element. If you want to wait for them all to complete, then use `Task.WhenAll`:

```
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Most other LINQ operators do not work as cleanly with asynchronous delegates. `Select` is pretty straightforward: you're just starting an asynchronous operation for each element.

Comment: @EliArbel: Yes. But an asynchronous method throwing synchronously is a very unusual case. Async methods should *only* throw sync exceptions if they are [boneheaded exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/). So I don't consider that an important use case.

Answer (score 9):

> does it have a certain use

Sure. With async and await inside a LINQ statement you can e.g. do something like this:

```
var tasks = foos.Select( async foo =>
    {
        var intermediate =  await DoSomethingAsync( foo );
        return await DoSomethingElseAsync( intermediate );
    } ).ToList();
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Without async/await inside a LINQ statement you're not awaiting anything inside the LINQ statement, so you can't process the result, or await for something else.

Without async/await, in the LINQ statement you're only starting tasks, but not waiting for them to complete. They'll still complete eventually, but it'll happen long after the control will leave the LINQ statement, so you can only access their results after the `WhenAll` line will complete, but not inside the LINQ statement.