# async within a LINQ code - Clarification?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

Almost every SO's answer regarding this topic , states that :

> [LINQ doesn't work perfectly with async](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868161/859154)

Also :

> [I recommend that you not think of this as "using async within LINQ"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113336/859154)

But in Stephen's book there is a sample for :

> **Problem:** You have a collection of tasks to await, and you want to do some
>   processing on each task after it completes. However, you want to do
>   the processing for each one *as soon as* it completes, **not** waiting for
>   any of the other tasks.

One of the recommended solutions was :

```
static async Task<int> DelayAndReturnAsync(int val)
{
 await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(val));
 return val;
}

// This method now prints "1", "2", and "3".
static async Task ProcessTasksAsync()
{
 // Create a sequence of tasks.
 Task<int> taskA = DelayAndReturnAsync(2);
 Task<int> taskB = DelayAndReturnAsync(3);
 Task<int> taskC = DelayAndReturnAsync(1);
 var tasks = new[] { taskA, taskB, taskC };
 var processingTasks = tasks.Select(async t =>
    {
    var result = await t;
    Trace.WriteLine(result);
    }).ToArray();

// Await all processing to complete
await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);

}
```

**Question #1:**

I don't understand why now `async` inside a LINQ statement - does work . Didn't we just say  "*don't* think about using `async` within LINQ" ?

**Question #2:**

When the control reaches the `await t` here — What is actually happen? Does the control leaves the `ProcessTasksAsync` method ? or does it leaves the anonymous method and continue the iteration ?

Comment: That "don't think about ..." statement  wasn't imperative. None of the texts you quote say that async won't work with Linq - just hat it's not a perfect match.

Comment: A good read by Stephen Toub, if you haven't come across it yet: [Tasks, Monads, and LINQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2013/04/03/tasks-monads-and-linq.aspx).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I don't understand why now async inside a LINQ statement - does work . Didn't we just say "don't think about using async within LINQ" ?

`async` *mostly* doesn't work with LINQ because `IEnumerable<T>` extensions don't always infer the delegate type properly and defer to `Action<T>`. They have no special understanding of the `Task` class. This means the actual async delegate becomes `async void`, which is bad. In the case of `Enumerable.Select`, we have an overload which returns a `Func<T>` (which in turn will be `Func<Task>` in our case), which is equivalent to `async Task`, hence it works fine for async use-cases.

> When the control reaches the await t here — What is actually happen? Does the control leaves the ProcessTasksAsync method ?

No, it doesn't. `Enumerable.Select` is about projecting all elements in the sequence. This means that for each element in the collection, `await t` which will yield control back to the iterator, which will continue iterating all elements. That's why you later have to `await Task.WhenAll`, to ensure all elements have finished execution.

Answer (score 3):

**Question 1:**

The difference is that each task is **continued** with additional processing which is: `Trace.WriteLine(result);`. In the link you pointed to, that code does not change anything, just creates overhead of awaiting and wrapping with another task.

**Question 2:**

> When the control reaches the await t here — What is actually happen?

It awaits for the result of `ProcessTasksAsync`'s task, then continue with `Trace.WriteLine(result);`. We can say that the control leaves the `ProcessTasksAsync` method when we have the result and the processing is still inside the anonymous method.

At the end, we have `await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);` which will await for all tasks including the additional processing (`Trace.WriteLine(result);`) to complete before continuing but **each task does not await for the others** to continue executing: `Trace.WriteLine(result);`

Answer (score 0):

It will be better this way:

```
static async Task<int> DelayAndReturnAsync(int val)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(val));
    return val;
}
static async Task AwaitAndProcessAsync(Task<int> task)
{
    var result = await task;
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
// This method now prints "1", "2", and "3".
static async Task ProcessTasksAsync()
{
    // Create a sequence of tasks.
    Task<int> taskA = DelayAndReturnAsync(2);
    Task<int> taskB = DelayAndReturnAsync(3);
    Task<int> taskC = DelayAndReturnAsync(1);
    var tasks = new[] { taskA, taskB, taskC };
    var processingTasks = tasks.Select(AwaitAndProcessAsync).ToArray();
    // Await all processing to complete
    await Task.WhenAll(processingTasks);
}
```

Array of Task, because AwaitAndProcessAsync returns Task.