# Async await in linq select

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I need to modify an existing program and it contains following code:

```
var inputs = events.Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
                   .Select(t => t.Result)
                   .Where(i => i != null)
                   .ToList();
```

But this seems very weird to me, first of all the use of `async` and `await`in the select. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23113336/3410196) by Stephen Cleary I should be able to drop those.

Then the second `Select` which selects the result. Doesn't this mean the task isn't async at all and is performed synchronously (so much effort for nothing), or will the task be performed asynchronously and when it's done the rest of the query is executed?

Should I write the above code like following according to [another answer by Stephen Cleary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21868161/3410196):

```
var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(events.Select(ev => ProcessEventAsync(ev)));
var inputs = tasks.Where(result => result != null).ToList();
```

and is it completely the same like this?

```
var inputs = (await Task.WhenAll(events.Select(ev => ProcessEventAsync(ev))))
                                       .Where(result => result != null).ToList();
```

While i'm working on this project I'd like to change the first code sample but I'm not too keen on changing (apparantly working) async code. Maybe I'm just worrying for nothing and all 3 code samples do exactly the same thing?

ProcessEventsAsync looks like this:

```
async Task<InputResult> ProcessEventAsync(InputEvent ev) {...}
```

Comment: What's the return type of ProceesEventAsync?

Comment: @tede24 It's `Task<InputResult>` with `InputResult` being a custom class.

Comment: Your versions are much easier to read in my opinion.
However, you have forgotten to `Select` the results from the tasks before your  `Where`.

Comment: And InputResult has a Result property right?

Comment: @tede24 Result is property of task not my class. And @Max the await should make sure I get the results without accessing `Result` property of task

Comment: Yes. Sorry. I was just updating my comment but it got to stale to edit in the process.
I found the name `tasks` slightly misleading, fyi. It makes me expect an enumerable of task.

Comment: There is also a way for a lazy developer to make this code async. Just add `ToList()` to create all tasks before waiting for results like so `events.Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev)).ToList().Select(t => t.Result)...`. This has a slight performance impact compared to `WaitAll()` but is negligible in most cases.

Comment: @Poma Interesting, going to test that out. When you write it like that I find it harder to see what the code is supposed to be doing though, the example from the accepted answer is more clear to me.

Comment: `ToList()` walks through all elements of collection and forces immediate query evaluation before passing control further. Thus launching all async tasks before `.Select(t => t.Result)` starts evaluating

Comment: The original question would be easier to read if the terms "parallel" and "sequentially" were used instead of "asynchronous" and "synchronous".

Answer (score 359, accepted):

```
var inputs = events.Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
                   .Select(t => t.Result)
                   .Where(i => i != null)
                   .ToList();
```

> But this seems very weird to me, first of all the use of async and await in the select. According to this answer by Stephen Cleary I should be able to drop those.

The call to `Select` is valid. These two lines are essentially identical:

```
events.Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
events.Select(ev => ProcessEventAsync(ev))
```

(There's a minor difference regarding how a synchronous exception would be thrown from `ProcessEventAsync`, but in the context of this code it doesn't matter at all.)

> Then the second Select which selects the result. Doesn't this mean the task isn't async at all and is performed synchronously (so much effort for nothing), or will the task be performed asynchronously and when it's done the rest of the query is executed?

It means that the query is blocking. So it is not really asynchronous.

Breaking it down:

```
var inputs = events.Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
```

will first start an asynchronous operation for each event. Then this line:

```
                   .Select(t => t.Result)
```

will wait for those operations to complete one at a time (first it waits for the first event's operation, then the next, then the next, etc).

This is the part I don't care for, because it blocks and also would wrap any exceptions in `AggregateException`.

> and is it completely the same like this?

```
var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(events.Select(ev => ProcessEventAsync(ev)));
var inputs = tasks.Where(result => result != null).ToList();

var inputs = (await Task.WhenAll(events.Select(ev => ProcessEventAsync(ev))))
                                       .Where(result => result != null).ToList();
```

Yes, those two examples are equivalent. They both start all asynchronous operations (`events.Select(...)`), then asynchronously wait for all the operations to complete in any order (`await Task.WhenAll(...)`), then proceed with the rest of the work (`Where...`).

Both of these examples are different from the original code. The original code is blocking and will wrap exceptions in `AggregateException`.

Comment: Cheers for clearing that up! So instead of the exceptions wrapped up into an `AggregateException` I would get multiple separate exceptions in the second code?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: No, in both the old and new code, only the first exception would be raised. But with `Result` it would be wrapped in `AggregateException`.

Comment: I'm getting a deadlock in my ASP.NET MVC Controller using this code. I solved it using Task.Run( … ). I don't have a good feeling about it. However, it finished just right when running into an async xUnit test. What's going on?

Comment: @SuperJMN: I suspect you're [blocking on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Comment: @StephenCleary I have read your post briefly, but I can't seem to find a fix for it, since you state that using ConfigureAwait(false) is a hack :) My code currently looks like:             `var models = dtos.Select(async x => new CuentaModel
            {
                CodigoCuenta = x.Codigo,
                DescripcionCuenta = x.Descripcion,
                ContratosList = await GetContratos(x.Id),
            }).Select(x => x.Result);`

The problem here is that some properties in the initializer are calculated asynchronously :(

Comment: @SuperJMN: Replace `stuff.Select(x => x.Result);` with `await Task.WhenAll(stuff)`

Comment: @StephenCleary, could you elaborate why 2 lines below behave the same? wouldn't async/await syntax create a bunch of state machines that could be avoided if Task syntax was used?

`events.Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
events.Select(ev => ProcessEventAsync(ev))`

Comment: @DanielS: They're *essentially* the same. There are some differences such as state machines, capturing context, behavior of synchronous exceptions. More info at https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html

Comment: @StephenCleary is there a way initialize all the tasks and to not wait until all the tasks are completed, but to work with the results as soon as they are ready?

Comment: @user33276346: I usually recommend refactoring by adding an asynchronous method. E.g., if the original tasks represent "get" and you want to "process" as they complete, then make a new method that is "get-and-process" and call that one instead of "get" when starting all the tasks.

Answer (score 52):

I used this code:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectAsync<TSource,TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> method)
{
  return await Task.WhenAll(source.Select(async s => await method(s)));
}
```

like this:

```
var result = await sourceEnumerable.SelectAsync(async s=>await someFunction(s,other params));
```

---

Edit:

Some people have raised the issue of concurrency, like when you are accessing a database and you can't run two tasks at the same time. So here is a more complex version that also allows for a specific concurrency level:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectAsync<TSource, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> method,
    int concurrency = int.MaxValue)
{
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(concurrency);
    try
    {
        return await Task.WhenAll(source.Select(async s =>
        {
            try
            {
                await semaphore.WaitAsync();
                return await method(s);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        }));
    } finally
    {
        semaphore.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Without a parameter it behaves exactly as the simpler version above. With a parameter of 1 it will execute all tasks sequentially:

```
var result = await sourceEnumerable.SelectAsync(async s=>await someFunction(s,other params),1);
```

Note: **Executing the tasks sequentially doesn't mean the execution will stop on error!**

Just like with a larger value for concurrency or no parameter specified, all the tasks will be executed and if any of them fail, the resulting AggregateException will contain the thrown exceptions.

If you want to execute tasks one after the other and fail at the first one, try another solution, like the one suggested by xhafan (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64363463/379279)

Comment: This just wraps the existing functionality in a more obscure way imo

Comment: The alternative is var result = await Task.WhenAll(sourceEnumerable.Select(async s=>await someFunction(s,other params)). It works, too, but it's not LINQy

Comment: Shouldn't `Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> method` contain the `other params` mentioned on the second bit of code?

Comment: The extra parameters are external, depending on the function that I want to execute, they are irrelevant in the context of the extension method.

Comment: That's a lovely extension method. Not sure why it was deemed "more obscure" - it's semantically analogous to the synchronous `Select()`, so is an elegant drop-in.

Comment: The `async` and `await` inside the first lambda is redundant. The SelectAsync method can simply be written as: `return await Task.WhenAll(source.Select(method));`

Comment: Indeed @Nathan, why have the ```await``` at all? -  ```public static Task<TResult[]> SelectAsync<TSource,TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> method) { return Task.WhenAll(source.Select(x => method(x))); }```

Comment: Beware that when this implementation of .SelectAsync() is used by a code using NHibernate session, it might produce `A command is already in progress` exception as it uses the NHibernate session concurrently. For this reason, I used this https://stackoverflow.com/a/64363463/379279 solution.

Comment: As a side note, the `SelectAsync` method that includes a `concurrency` parameter is most commonly named [`ForEachAsync`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564506/nesting-await-in-parallel-foreach). It can be implemented in various ways, differing usually on how they handle exceptions, and most probably a built-in implementation will be added soon ([`Parallel.ForEachAsync`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1946)).

Comment: @nrofis [eliding async/await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) is not a neutral modification of the OP's code. It could result in leaked tasks, in case the `method` fails synchronously *sometimes*. The `using var semaphore` is OK though IMHO.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I don't think this is the case here, but thanks for your awareness. I saw you've totally reverted my edit, the code formatting, and the `using`...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, from your link: "**Do** consider eliding when the method is just a passthrough or overload." This is the case here. This is the reason I removed them. For `Select`, especially in this simple implementation, you can elide the redundant `async`/`await` safely.

Comment: Guys, fighting over eliding is pointless, as it is not in the scope of the question or my answer. I prefer not to "elide" because you can always add more code later without changing the method signature, but in this case it is not important to the way one uses the extension method.

Comment: No one fighting :) I was just wanted to format the code a little bit... Not a big deal...

Comment: @nrofis "passthrough or overload" means that a method includes just a call to another method, and nothing else. But inside the `SelectAsync` lots of other things happening. If for example the first invocation of the `method` succeeds and the second fails, and you elid async/await inside the `Select` delegates, the `SelectAsync` will return a faulted `Task` without awaiting the completion of the task created by the first successful `method` invocation. This task will be a leaked fire-and-forget task. A library method is not supposed to do things like that.

Comment: @nrofis as for the `using` edit, sorry for revoking it. I was too lazy to do a selective revoke.  Please consider redoing this edit.

Answer (score 43):

Existing code is working, but is blocking the thread.

```
.Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
```

creates a new Task for every event, but

```
.Select(t => t.Result)
```

blocks the thread waiting for each new task to end.

In the other hand your code produce the same result but keeps asynchronous.

Just one comment on your first code. This line

```
var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(events...
```

will produce a single Task<TResult[]> so the variable should be named in singular.

Finally your last code make the same but is more succinct.

For reference: [Task.Wait](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait) / [Task.WhenAll](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_WhenAll_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Threading_Tasks_Task__)

Comment: So the first code block is in fact executed synchronously?

Comment: Yes, because accessing Result produces a Wait which blocks the thread. In the other hand When produces a new Task you can await for.

Comment: Coming back to this question and looking at your remark about the name of the `tasks` variable, you're completely right. Horrible choice, they're not even tasks as they get awaited right away. I'll just leave the question as is though

Comment: Just came by this thread. @AlexanderDerck - why not edit the answer? It gave me confusion for a while before getting to this answer. Also using var usually gets you to this point when it matters.

Answer (score 26):

I have the same problem as @KTCheek in that I need it to execute sequentially. However I figured I would try using IAsyncEnumerable (introduced in .NET Core 3) and await foreach (introduced in C# 8). Here's what I have come up with:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions {
    public static async IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> SelectAsync<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> selector) {
        foreach (var item in source) {
            yield return await selector(item);
        }
    }
}

public static class IAsyncEnumerableExtensions {
    public static async Task<List<TSource>> ToListAsync<TSource>(this IAsyncEnumerable<TSource> source) {
        var list = new List<TSource>();

        await foreach (var item in source) {
            list.Add(item);
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

This can be consumed by saying:

```
var inputs = await events.SelectAsync(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev)).ToListAsync();
```

Update: Alternatively you can add a reference to [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) and then you can say:

```
var inputs = await events
    .ToAsyncEnumerable()
    .SelectAwait(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: These two operators are included in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async) package, with the names `SelectAwait` and `ToListAsync`, along with lots of other LINQ-style operators.

Comment: Actually no, your `SelectAsync` operates on `IEnumerable<T>`s. The aforementioned `SelectAwait` operates on `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`s. You would need to convert it first, by calling the `ToAsyncEnumerable` extension method.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias, I've updated my answer with the alternative solution.

Answer (score 23):

I prefer this as an extension method:

```
public static async Task<IEnumerable<T>> WhenAll<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    return await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

So that it is usable with method chaining:

```
var inputs = await events
  .Select(async ev => await ProcessEventAsync(ev))
  .WhenAll()
```

Comment: You shouldn't call the method `Wait` when it's not actually waiting.  It's creating a task that is complete when all of the tasks are complete.  Call it `WhenAll`, like the `Task` method it emulates.  It's also pointless for the method to be `async`.  Just call `WhenAll` and be done with it.

Comment: A bit of a useless wrapper in my opinion when it just calls the original method

Comment: @Servy fair point, but I don't particularly like any of the name options. WhenAll makes it sounds like an event which it is not quite.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck the advantage is that you can use it in method chaining.

Comment: @Servy, actually you can't remove the async and await from the extension method. You get this error:
```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T[]>' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>>'
```
Because it doesn't know Task<T> is covariant with T

Comment: @Daryl because `WhenAll` returns an evaluated list (it's not evaluated lazily), an argument can be made to use the `Task<T[]>` return type to signify that. When awaited, this will still be able to use Linq, but also communicates that it is not lazy.

Comment: Extending @Daryl's good point further, we can reduce further to: ```public static Task<T[]> WhenAll<T>(this IEnumerable<Task<T> > tasks) { return Task.WhenAll(tasks); }```

Answer (score 17):

With current methods available in Linq it looks quite ugly:

```
var tasks = items.Select(
    async item => new
    {
        Item = item,
        IsValid = await IsValid(item)
    });
var tuples = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
var validItems = tuples
    .Where(p => p.IsValid)
    .Select(p => p.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Hopefully following versions of .NET will come up with more elegant tooling to handle collections of tasks and tasks of collections.

Answer (score 8):

I wanted to call `Select(...)` but ensure it ran in sequence because running in parallel would cause some other concurrency problems, so I ended up with this.
I cannot call `.Result` because it will block the UI thread.

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async Task<IEnumerable<TResult>> SelectInSequenceAsync<TSource, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, Task<TResult>> asyncSelector)
    {
        var result = new List<TResult>();
        foreach (var s in source)
        {
            result.Add(await asyncSelector(s));
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var inputs = events.SelectInSequenceAsync(ev => ProcessEventAsync(ev))
                   .Where(i => i != null)
                   .ToList();
```

I am aware that Task.WhenAll is the way to go when we can run in parallel.

Comment: Upvoted. I would prefer a return type of `Task<IList<TResult>>` (or even better `Task<TResult[]>`) instead of `Task<IEnumerable<TResult>>`. The later conveys the notion of [deferred execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324033/what-are-the-benefits-of-a-deferred-execution-in-linq), which is not applicable in this case. After the completion of the `Task`, the resulting `IEnumerable<TResult>` is fully materialized, since it is based on a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 3):

"Just because you can doesn't mean you should."

You can probably use async/await in LINQ expressions such that it will behave exactly as you want it to, but will any other developer reading your code still understand its behavior and intent?

(In particular: Should the async operations be run in parallel or are they intentionally sequential? Did the original developer even think about it?)

This is also shown clearly by [the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011656/async-await-in-linq-select), which seems to have been asked by a developer trying to understand someone else's code, without knowing its intent. To make sure this does not happen again, it may be best to rewrite the LINQ expression as a loop statement, if possible.