# Entity LINQ query to slow

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I'm new to the C#, I have a database that someone else designed, query works great, but compared with SQL, it's 10 times slower.

I made mistakes here for sure, anybody have tips to speed this up a little bit. This model is for displaying in table, and I converting `int` to `ENUM` and calculating discount for display.

Code is:

```
var results = from w in db.Washes.AsEnumerable()
              join t in db.Wash_Types.AsEnumerable() on w.WashTypeId equals t.Id
              join a in db.Accounts.AsEnumerable() on w.AccountId equals a.Id
              orderby w.Id descending
              select new AllWashesTable
                    {
                        Id = w.Id,
                        WashTime = w.WashTime,
                        WashTimeEnd = w.WashTimeEnd,
                        Name = a.Name,
                        Client = (w.Client != null ? w.Client.Naziv : ""),
                        MobileNumber = a.MobileNumber,
                        Identification = w.Identification,
                        WashType = WashTypeShowEnum.WashTypeShowEnumToString((WashTypeShowEnum.WashType) w.WashTypeId),
                        Price = int.Parse(t.WashPrice) * (1 - w.Discount) + "",
                        Discount = w.Discount
                    };
return results.ToList();
```

Seems all my entity queries are at least 5+ times slower than SQL. Somewhere I am making some mistake.

Comment: Why do you call `AsEnumerable()`?

Comment: @AleksAndreev can't call method for converting type(int) to Enum(string) without `AsEnumerable()?`

Comment: Problem is, you loose all server side filtering and such. You have to do conversions in read-only properties in `AllWashesTable `for example and remove the `AsEnumerable()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the use of `AsEnumerable`.  When the query gets executed (in your case the `results.ToList()`), Everything that appears after it, will be evaluated using linq-to-objects. It means that your joins will not be handled by DB. You will fetch all the records from the tables.

However, your function `WashTypeShowEnum.WashTypeShowEnumToString` will not be recognized by entity framework.

You might want to move the `AsEnumerable` to the end and then `select` the results.

```
var results = (from w in db.Washes
              join t in db.Wash_Types on w.WashTypeId equals t.Id
              join a in db.Accounts on w.AccountId equals a.Id
              orderby w.Id descending
              select new {w, a, t}).AsEnumerable().Select(arg=> new AllWashesTable
                    {
                        Id = arg.w.Id,
                        WashTime = arg.w.WashTime,
                        WashTimeEnd = arg.w.WashTimeEnd,
                        Name = arg.a.Name,
                        Client = (arg.w.Client != null ? arg.w.Client.Naziv : ""),
                        MobileNumber = arg.a.MobileNumber,
                        Identification = arg.w.Identification,
                        WashType = WashTypeShowEnum.WashTypeShowEnumToString((WashTypeShowEnum.WashType) arg.w.WashTypeId),
                        Price = int.Parse(arg.t.WashPrice) * (1 - arg.w.Discount) + "",
                        Discount = arg.w.Discount
                    };
return results.ToList();
```

Comment: I measured time for query and it's not to much slow. Problem was DevExpress table that is slow in populating Rows. I didn't managed to resolve that issue. But you helped me with this more logical approach, I learned something and made more faster Entity Query. Accepted. :)

Comment: Ofir, any hint to make this Async method. Enumerable can not be async.  Any help here? :)

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011656/async-await-in-linq-select)