# Cannot convert Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity to System.Threading.Task.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity>

Tags: c#

Below method gives me error at line "await tableRecords.Add( newprops );" on parameter newprops saying

> cannot convert to  System.Threading.Task.Task<Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.DynamicTableEntity>. What wrong am I doing here??

I am trying to add new values in my table records which I am inserting in an Azure table storage.

```
 public async Task WriteToTable( Stream lines, DataClass dataclass,
               Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, Task<(string, string)>> genKeys,
               Func<Dictionary<string, EntityProperty>, Task<List<string>>> generateColumns, List<string> columnsList, DynamicTableEntity tableEntry,
               bool upsert )
            {
                const int BatchSize = 100;
                if( HasPartitionAndRowKey( dataclass.TableSchema.Fields ) )
                {
                    genKeys = ( Dictionary<string, EntityProperty> props ) => Task.FromResult( (props["PartitionKey"].StringValue, props["RowKey"].ToString()) );
    
                }
    
                var tableRecords = ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields )
            .Select( async props =>
            {   var (partitionKey, rowKey) = await genKeys( props );
                return new DynamicTableEntity( partitionKey, rowKey, string.Empty, props );
            } ).ToList();
    
                if( columnsList != null )
                {
                    var newColumnValues = ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields )
            .Select( async prop => { await generateColumns( prop ); } ).ToList();
                    var arr = newColumnValues.ToArray();
                    var newprops = new DynamicTableEntity(); 
                    for( int i = 0; i < columnsList.Count; i++ )
                    {
                        newprops.Properties.Add( columnsList[i], EntityProperty.CreateEntityPropertyFromObject( arr[i] ) );
                       await tableRecords.Add( newprops );
                    }
                    
    
                    await BatchInsertIntoTableStorage( BatchSize, tableRecords, upsert );
                }
    
                await BatchInsertIntoTableStorage( BatchSize, tableRecords, upsert );
    
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to `await` the `tableRecords.Add(newprops);`. Awaiting is meant for `async` functions while

Your tableRecords are a list already:

```
var tableRecords = ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields )
            .Select( async props =>
            {   var (partitionKey, rowKey) = await genKeys( props );
                return new DynamicTableEntity( partitionKey, rowKey, string.Empty, props );
            } ).ToList();
```

Change `await tableRecords.Add( newprops );` to `tableRecords.Add( newprops );` and you'll be fine.

Basically what your error says is that it can't await `void`

```
public void Add (T item);
```

It needs to await a `Task` and that's not what add returns.

#### Wait for select

All the above is valid, but you also need break your select and await. `WhenAll` are done, create your list.

```
var tasks = await Task.WhenAll(ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields)
            .Select( async props = await genKeys( props )));
var tableRecords =  tasks.Select((partitionKey, rowKey) => new DynamicTableEntity(partitionKey, rowKey, string.Empty, props )).ToList();
```

[Async await in linq select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011656/async-await-in-linq-select)

Comment: did that and it still gives the same error

Comment: Did you rebuild and rerun;

Comment: I just noticed the async in you select. This is answered in another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011656/async-await-in-linq-select

Comment: can you please edit the answer with the changes in my code so i mark it as answer

Comment: Try the updated code. I did not have a chance to run it through a compiler. Let me know what's what.

Comment: I guess you missed props, so here I tried this and this gives me error on .Select saying cannot be inferred from usage.
"  var tasks = await Task.WhenAll( ReadCSV( lines, dataclass.TableSchema.Fields )
            .Select( async props => await genKeys( props ) ) );
            var tableRecords = tasks.Select(props => ( partitionKey, rowKey ) => new DynamicTableEntity( partitionKey, rowKey, string.Empty, props ) ).ToList();"

Comment: tried different other way but unable to Convert!! :/