# How to create IAsyncEnumerable from an enumerable of tasks

Tags: c#, .net, linq, async-await, iasyncenumerable

```
var moviePromises = this.watchlist.Select(async e => await this.GetMovieFromWatchlistEntry(e));

var movies = await Task.WhenAll(moviePromises);

foreach (var movie in movies)
{
   // dostuff
}
```

When I am doing the following it seems that all tasks created in (`GetMovieFromWatchlistEntry`) and are executed at the same time. but I want that at each step of the iteration a single task is created and awaited (lazy evaluation). I guess this is possible with `IAsyncEnumerable`, but how can I create a `IAsyncEnumerable` from my existing `moviePromises` enumerable?

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35011656/async-await-in-linq-select "Async await in linq select") question, and specifically [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66331594/11178549) answer by nfplee.

Answer (score 2):

> I want that at each step of the iteration a single task is created and awaited... I guess this is possible with IAsyncEnumerable

`IAsyncEnumerable` is for when you need to asynchronously determine the *length* of the sequence. If each item is asynchronous but the *length* is well-known, then `IEnumerable<T>` is fine - just enumerate it with `foreach` and `await` what you want to do to each item:

```
foreach (var watchItem in this.watchList)
{
  var movie = await this.GetMovieFromWatchlistEntry(watchItem);
  // dostuff
}
```

> from my existing moviePromises enumerable?

My code above assumes you can change `moviePromises`. If that's not the case for some reason, then you can still enumerate and `await` them one at a time [like this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76543731/263693). However, if `moviePromises` at some point in the future has a `ToList()` or something like that stuck on the end, then all the tasks are started at that time.

Answer (score 1):

> I want that at each step of the iteration a single task is created and awaited

So, something like this?

```
foreach(var moviePromise in moviePromises)
{
    var result = await moviePromise;
    // do stuff on the result
}
```