# C# Entity Framework error on async methods

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

I have already seen this, but I am experiencing another problem.

I have this service class for managing ASP.NET identity roles:

```
public class RoleService : IRoleService
{
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

    public RoleService(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        this._roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationRole role)
    {
        return await this._roleManager.CreateAsync(role);
    }
}
```

As suggested by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868087), I use the `CreateAsync` method like this to avoid using LINQ `foreach`:

```
private async Task PopulateRoles()
{
     var roles = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

     // Used LINQ foreach previously but I coded this way instead to follow the related questions's answer
     var tasks = roles.Select(role =>
                           this._roleService.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole(role)))
                      .ToList();

     await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

However, this results in an error when `await this.PopulateRoles()` is executed.

> Entity Framework: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.

Searching for this error only leads me to a suggestion of adding a `ToList()` in my Select LINQ. How can I fix it?

Comment: `RoleManager` instances are not thread-safe. Multiple `CreateAsync` tasks are fighting for the same connection. You should do this in a traditional serial way.

Comment: i'll make the creation of roles in a synchronous way?

Comment: Yes, that's what I suggest.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. i'll wait for others' comment (if there's still any :D)

Comment: Is generating multiple instances of `RoleService` a problem for you?

Comment: i dont feel there is a need to create multiple instances of `RoleService`. Is there?

Comment: If you only have one instance of `RoleManager`, you wont be able to concurrently create multiple users. Is that an issue? Can you simply iterate them using `foreach` and `await` each one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lays with the `RoleManager<T>` which internally is given a single `DbContext` as we can see [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/5d29d11ccb8b0973c4448903ad9ab985234b957c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework/RoleStore.cs):

```
public class RoleStore<TRole, TContext, TKey> : 
        IQueryableRoleStore<TRole>, 
        IRoleClaimStore<TRole>
        where TRole : IdentityRole<TKey>
        where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
        where TContext : DbContext
{
    public RoleStore(TContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
        }
        Context = context;
    }
}
```

`DbContext` itself can't handle concurrent calls. The alternative would be to execute each of the calls inside a `foreach` and `await` each one:

```
private async Task PopulateRoles()
{
     var roles = new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" };

     foreach (var role in roles)
     {
         await _roleService.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole(role));
     }
}
```

This way, though you don't have the benefit of applying all roles concurrently, you do still take advantage of the async nature of the IO call, instead of a blocking synchronous call.