# What leads to mySQL command concurrency issue with DataReader in ASP.Net Core, and how do I resolve it?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1, sqldatareader

I just migrated my application from ASP.Net Core 2.2 to 3.1, and I have a bug I don't understand.  It's a fairly straightforward MVC app with a mySQL DB, and I'm using EF Core - Identity to manage what they call "policy-based" authorization, aka 'claims-based' auth.

The main Class/Model is a Family Profile.  A given User can have 2 levels of claims to different Families - they can be either a Parent or a Caregiver.  The User dashboard View shows a few lists: A list of children in any Parent-Family, a list of Caregivers authorized for Parent-Families, and a list of Caregiver-Families.

This is the Controller code that sends all that info to the view.  The problem is that the `foreach` loop is generating an error in the browser:

"InvalidOperationException: Cannot set MySqlCommand.CommandText when there is an open DataReader for this command; it must be closed first."

It only happens when the User has a Caregiver relationship with a Family, since the conditional prevents you from entering the `foreach`, but part of my confusion is why this is an issue inside this loop when it seems like I am making very similar requests to the DB in other places.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5440168/exception-there-is-already-an-open-datareader-associated-with-this-connection-w) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27667252/c-sharp-entity-framework-error-on-async-methods), and it seems like maybe the 2nd one is more relevant, so I tried adding the `await` piece and making the query method Async inside the foreach loop (it had been just 1 line in there), but it didn't fix the problem. Maybe I put it in the wrong place? The first question helped me understand what's going on under the hood, but I don't know where in my code I would actually implement any of it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  var userId = this.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value;
  var currentUser = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
  var userFamilies = (_db.Families.Where(entry => (entry.ParentId == currentUser.Id))).ToList();

  if (_db.Caregivers.Select(entry => (entry.CaregiverId == currentUser.Id)) != null)
  {

    var userCareFamilies = new List<Family>();
    var careFamilies = _db.CaregiverFamilies
    .Where(c => c.CaregiverId == currentUser.Id);
    if (careFamilies.Count() != 0)
    {
      foreach (CaregiverFamily cf in careFamilies)
      {
        var thisFamily = await _db.Families.FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.FamilyId == cf.FamilyId);
        userCareFamilies.Add(thisFamily);
      }
    }
    ViewBag.CareFamilies = userCareFamilies;
  }
```

Comment: See following : https://downloads.mysql.com/mwg-internal/de5fs23hu73ds/progress?id=UabEpE2wRQ0jI9c5sv3jxm92AqcLLY_7DDaaljFR7V0,

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line:

```cs
var careFamilies = _db.CaregiverFamilies
.Where(c => c.CaregiverId == currentUser.Id);
```

Because you are not materializing the query (via `ToList` etc), it keeps the connection open while you're iterating through the results.

Try using

```cs
var careFamilies = _db.CaregiverFamilies
.Where(c => c.CaregiverId == currentUser.Id).ToList();
```

On a side note, you're mixing Async (`FirstOrDefaultAsync`) and Sync (`ToList`) methods. I'd suggest sticking to one or the other.