# Mixing LINQ with async (getting payload from a seed)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, async-await, system.reactive

I have a collection of seeds

```
var seeds = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

From each seed I want to run an async method that performs some calculation with the seed:

```
async Task<int> Calculation(int seed);
```

My goal is to perform a select like this:

```
var results = from seed in seeds
              let calculation = await Calculation(seed)
              select new { seed, calculation };
```

Unfortunately, this syntax isn't allowed using LINQ.

How can I make the "results" variable contain both the seed and the calculation?

(I would appreciate any answer, but specially if it's using System.Reactive's `Observable`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868087/how-to-await-a-list-of-tasks-asynchronously-using-linq Here answer by the Stephen Cleary, about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an Rx solution:

```
var seeds = new [] {1, 2, 3, 4};
var results = Observable.ToObservable(seeds)
    .SelectMany(async i => new { seed = i, calculation = await Calculation(i)})
    .ToEnumerable();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following using [`WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160384(v=vs.110).aspx) static method:

```
var r= await Task.WhenAll(seeds.Select(async seed =>new {
                                                          Seed= seed,
                                                          Result = await Calculation(seed) 
                                                        }
                                      )
                         );
```

Comment: There's no reason for `Task.Run` to be used here.

Comment: Hi @Servy, thanks for pointed out, is it correct with my last update?

Comment: You could also replace the statement lambda with an expression lambda and just inline the calculation call, simplifying the code a fair bit.  The formatting is also...not ideal.

Comment: you caught me doing it ;)

Answer (score 1):

Change your async function to return both the calculated number and the given `seed`:

```
public static async Task<Output> Calculation(int seed)
{
    return new Output { Seed = seed, Result = 0 };
}

public class Output
{
    public int Seed { get; set; }
    public int Result { get; set; }
}
```

Then use the linq to return a `Task[]` on which you can `WaitAll` or `WhenAll`: *([WaitAll vs WhenAll](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6123406/6400526))*

```
var seeds = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

var tasks = seeds.Select(Calculation);
var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

foreach (var item in results)
    Console.WriteLine($"seed: {item.Seed}, result: {item.Result}");
```

Comment: `WhenAlll` has a overload that takes in a `Enumerable<Task<TResult>>`, no need to call ToArray()

Comment: @ScottChamberlain - you are correct :) Thanks :) Fixed it. Originally I used `WaitAll` and had to pass an array.. but forgot to update that when changed